# What's the difference (if any) between writing $(n-1)/2$ and $\frac{n-1}{2}$?

Tags: notation

This might be a very basic question, but I've always wondered if there's any difference between these two forms, and under what circumstances may one be preferable to the other?

Comment: No difference. Purely a typesetting issue.

Comment: It also saves a little energy to not write out and keep track of the full \frac{...}{...} structure in LaTeX…although that might as well be called lethargy by others…

Comment: Personally, the fraction layout with $\frac{n - 1}{2}$ is more visually appealing. But of course, there isn't any difference between the two.

Comment: Typsetting in Latex is a pain in the ass.  Reading something by someone who is too lazy to typeset is also a pain in the ass.  n - 1/2 is interpreted as $n - \frac 12$ so that isn't what was intended.  $(n-1)/2$ is the untypeset $\frac{(n-1)}2$  with proper typesetting the brackets are not nesc.  $\frac{(n-1)}2 = \frac{n-1}2$.  However without typesetting it is impossible to type $\frac {n-1}2$.  Mathematically $a/b$ and $(a)/b$  and $\frac ab$ and $\frac {(a)}b$ are the same thing.  The only difference is typesetting which is printing; not math. But bad typesetting is HARD TO READ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. It is a formatting choice and one may be easier to use in a certain editor.

For example,
$$\frac{x^2+(2n+1)!}{2xy^n}$$
is much easier to read than $(x^2+(2n+1)!)/(2xy^n)$.

However, $\delta=\epsilon/2$ is probably easier to see than $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, especially if printed in small font.

Comment: Agreed.  That's why dfrac is my best friend.

Comment: Worth noting, if you don't typeset $\frac{n-1}2$ is impossible to type.  Thus you need parenthesis as $n-1/2$ will be interpreted as $n - \frac 12$.  I think it's *always* easier to read typeset although it is frequently *very* hard to type.